# Unable to Stream Audio via OBS Studio for HoI 4

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4, obs

I've been trying to get the game audio from hearts of iron IV streaming via OBS Studio (version 20.0.1). I have tried both the 64 bit and 32 bit versions

My sound settings are correct as I have been able to confirm that the sound streams fine from another game (Stardew Valley ... I have varied tastes ;))

I am able to correctly stream sounds from my discord server (that is currently set up using a different audio input).

When I'm just on my desktop, audio is successfully streamed from things like youtube or other random desktop sounds.

I am using a TurtleBeach PX22 headset. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a copyright protected music dlc installed. The game states that this forbids streaming the game with sound. So maybe they implemented some technical restriction so that OBS doesn't work.